# For bijection $f:A \rightarrow B$, prove that $f^{-1} \circ f = {\text {id}}_{A}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, proof-writing, proof-verification

I have to prove that for a bijection $f:A \rightarrow B$, $f^{-1} \circ  f = {\text {id}}_{A}$, where ${\text {id}_A}$ is the identity function of $A$, and we define $f^{-1}: B \rightarrow A$ by $f^{-1}(b) = a$ if $f(a)=b$. This definition is given by the homework prompt, so I think it's safe to assume it.

Here is my work:

> For $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, we have defined that if $f(a)=b$, then $f^{-1}(b)=a$, so $f^{-1}(f(a))=a$, so $f^{-1} \circ f:A\rightarrow A$. We know ${\text{id}}_A:A\rightarrow A$ is the bijective function s.t. $\forall a \in A,  {\text{id}}(a)=a$. As the domains of the functions are equal and $\forall a \in A, (f^{-1}\circ f)(a) = {\text {id}}_{A}(a)$, the two functions are equal.

Can someone please confirm whether it is sufficiently rigorous, or if not, suggest any improvements?

Comment: For the first part of the proof where you have said "we have defined $f(a)=b$ then $f^{-1}=b...$ is not complete. You have to use the fact that since $f$ is a bijective function there exists an inverse function call if $f^{-1}$. We know that is $f$ is bijective then so is $f^{-1}$...

Comment: It is important to comment why we can define $f^{-1}$ that way (bijectiveness of $f$ is crucial here). Besides that it looks good.

Comment: The definition $f^{-1}: B \rightarrow A$ by $f^{-1}(b) = a$ if $f(a)=b$ is given to me by the homework prompt, so I think I can assume it. Does that make it okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the given definition of $f^{-1}$, your proof is correct.

Depending on what you're allowed to assume, it may be necessary (or in any case, a good exercise) to prove that $f^{-1}:B \to A$, i.e., that the domain of $f^{-1}$ as given is $B$, and its codomain is $A$.